# counterexample of Riemann-Lebesgue lemma for non-Borel functions

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel measurable function. Then 
$$
\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{i\lambda x}d\mu(x)=0.
$$
I obtain this result by showing that it is true for $f=\sum_{k=1}^nb_k\chi_{(a_k,b_k)}$. And the collection of simple functions of the form $f=\sum_{k=1}^nb_k\chi_{(a_k,b_k)}$ is dense in Borel mesurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$.

Is there any counter-example that $f$ is only Lebesgue measurable but not Borel, and 
$$
\lim_{\lambda\to\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)e^{i\lambda x}d\mu(x)\neq 0?
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you should be using is that the set of simple functions you consider is dense in the space $L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$.

You will also have to use that the Fourier transform $\mathcal{F} : L^1 \rightarrow C_b$ is bounded (where $C_b$ is the space of bounded continuous functions with the sup-norm). You will also want to use that $C_0 \subset C_b$ is closed, where $C_0$ is the space of continuous functions vanishing at infinity.

The space of all Borel measurable functions has no natural norm in which your statement it true.

**Main point** Finally note that for every Lebsgue measurable function $f$, there is a Borel measurable function $g$ with $f=g$ a.e., so that $\hat{f} = \hat{g}$.

Thus it makes no difference which notion of measurability you take.